# Trying to return a random photo from a subreddit, but bot picks out video submissions too which doesn't work with set_image

Tags: python, discord.py

Basically, I want to put a condition that only picks out .jpeg links from the submissions of the subreddit. Because otherwise, currently, if a submission is a video, the bot is not able to load it in discord. Code as of now -

```
    async def aww(self,ctx, *, subred = "aww"):
        async with ctx.channel.typing():
         

            reddit = praw.Reddit(
                client_id ="",
                client_secret ="",
                username ="",
                password ="",
                user_agent ="")

            subreddit = reddit.subreddit("aww")
            all_subs = []

            top = subreddit.top(limit = 50)

            for submission in top:
                all_subs.append(submission)

            random_sub = random.choice(all_subs)

            name = random_sub.title
            url = random_sub.url

            

            embed = discord.Embed(color=0xc81f9f,
            title = "Stupid Aww Generator",
            description =f"{ctx.author.mention} Here's your aww moment: \n\n{name}")
            embed.set_image(url=url)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.guild.name}",)
            embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a better way to do this, but one way I would go about this is brute-checking for jpg or jpeg(or other image formats, for that matter)

```
# This is assuming your URL is consistent.
url = "hxxp://www.someurl.com/someimage.jpg"
file_format = url.split(".")[-1]
if file_format in ["jpg", "jpeg", ...]:
    # do embed
else:
    # fetch another random and check again
```

Or you could do regex matching on your URL string to see if it passes.
You may want to implement logic for when/if all 50 URLs lead to videos.